# Python, Return Difference of Time in Hours

Tags: python, time

As simple as I can put it, I have two date-times which are both strings, then converted to datetime objects. How can I return the difference of time formatted in hours as an integer, instead of a "datetime.timedelta" object?

```
  >>> start = '2016-10-21 00:00:00'
  >>> stop = '2017-01-5 10:05:19'

  >>> start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  >>> stop = datetime.datetime.strptime(stop, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

  >>> stop - start
  datetime.timedelta(76, 36319)
```

Comment: Do you want the hours to ignore minutes? Or round up/down as needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
stop = datetime.datetime.strptime(stop, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

(stop-start).total_seconds() / 3600
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a `timedelta` to seconds by doing:

```
>>> datetime.timedelta(76, 36319).total_seconds()
6602719.0
```

You can then convert this to minutes or hours accordingly.

You'll need to decide what to do when the timedelta represents an amount of time that isn't a exactly a full number of hours but a few hours and several minutes / seconds more.